# Using anchors in CKEditor with Drupal across several text inputs

Tags: drupal-7, anchor, ckeditor4.x

I'm currently working on a project in Drupal where the client has several content types containing multiple text inputs, each representing a paragraph in the final display.  Each text input can be edited using CKEditor.

I've now run into the problem that if i enter an anchor in one of the text fields, that anchor is not known in any of the other text fields using the ckeditor link dialog.  If i use the sharedspaces plugin for CKEditor to share the toolbar across instances, the problem persists.

So the question is: how can i add an anchor using CKEditor in one text input, and have it be recognised in another text input in the same form by CKEditor?